# One controller not working out of the two I used in my angular module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I used two controllers in my angular module, but one is not working, I don't know what is wrong, I've browsed online for solution but I can't get what's wrong.

```js
var app = angular.module('myWebsite', [])
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
});
app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {

 });
```

```html
<div ng-app="myWebsite">
<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
</div>
</div>
```

The secondCtrl is giving me error in my console. This is the error code it's giving me: angular.js:124 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=secondCtrl

Comment: No error. [It works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lb45dou/), please append your scripts to the bottom of the head tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the clearing of my browsing history got it solved

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new to angular Js, If you are running an angular app then mind the arrangements of cdn links. What is happening here is application don't know what is angular because it is compiling it before angular js library can be included which has its definition stored in it. So, when compiler don't know what the keyword is , it will throw error of `undefine`.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions, I finally got whatwent wrong. I had to clear my browsing history to get it solved, I think the first controller was cached or stored in my cookies. Just the clearing of my browsing history got it solved. Thanks alot

Comment: I'm glad, your issue has been resolved. You can answer your question and then accept it.